# Editorconfig: How to Get Warnings for All Uses of `public`

Tags: c#, intellisense, omnisharp, editorconfig

Because I'm not creating a library, I want to replace all uses of `public` inside my project to `internal`.

While I can do this with Find and Replace, is there a configuration that I can add to `.editorconfig` that will give me warnings about all uses of `public` so I automatically know if there's something I want to replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got an answer ***[here.](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4066#issuecomment-697045255)***

Sadly, what I want to do seems to be impossible.